# UrlRequest error (name 'HTTPSConnection' is not defined) kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

> Hi! I have a ready project written on kivy and python3. This program
>   works fine on all desktop OS (Windows, Linux, MacOS), but after
>   compiling into a .apk file, UrlRequest does not work for me. What I
>   just did not do, in buildozer;

```
-- requirements = pyopenssl,openssl,docutils,android,python3crystax,kivy
```

> and in

```
-- android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

> After installing the .apk file on the android and pressing the button 
>   to scrape the page of the site, programm produces an error

```
**name 'HTTPSConnection' is not defined**
```

> This is part of the code with UrlRequest:

```
def get_html(self, link):
    try:
        from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
        if isinstance(link, bytes):
            link = link.decode('utf-8')
        reg = UrlRequest(link, debug=True,
                         on_success=self.suc, on_error=self.err)
        while not reg.is_finished:
            sleep(0.5)
            Clock.tick()
    except HTTPError:
        pass

def suc(self, reg, result):
    self.add_widget(Label(
        text=str(result), font_size='15sp', color=(0, 0, 0, 1)
    ))

def err(self, reg, error):
    class Error(App):
        def build(self):
            win_report = BugReporter(txt_report=str(error))
            return win_report
    Error().run()
```

> in variable (link) inserts links from a dict.

```
dict_links = dict({
    "userful_programs": "https://pcompstart.com/?view=cat&category=1",
    "advice_on_computer": "https://pcompstart.com/?view=cat&category=2",
    "user_windows": "https://pcompstart.com/?view=cat&category=3",
    "articles_in_theme": "https://pcompstart.com/?view=cat&category=4",
    "popular_program": "https://pcompstart.com/?view=cat&category=5",
    "other": "https://pcompstart.com/?view=cat&category=6"})
```

> Full file logs for my buildozer.spec with log_level = 2, attached in
>   this link;
>   https://15530009509605697547.googlegroups.com/attach/38c18b633925d/logcat.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFE1tvgVU8m0abaquknNDEzcXf_tgIMDdxEzo1tMSLUhqzNrto84pYWSc4sPxksIpmwEkAWhL_2IO2dptE2TLwFKzKJ535Vct_CDD_BgCz1M2G7u50
>
> Thanks!
>
> Or if in the same file I will execute  --

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
```

> Then after compilation on android I get error --

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSConnection'
```

> Or if i will execute  --

```
import ssl
```

> Then after compilation on android I get error --

```
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
```

> Likely kivy compiling without SSL support. This is bug or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether this will help, I'm newbie, but I went through very similar ordeal last few days.

In essence I was struggling with simple HTTPS request. I've tried all the possible libraries such as urllib, urllib2, requests and kivy's UrlRequest with no luck. At first I've tried python3 (same as you) and then switched to python2 as it seems to be producing less errors in general (not sure whether thats actually true).

At the end I've ended up with the same error "HTTPSconnection not defined", tried hundred of things and in the end putting "httplib2" into requirements (buildozer.spec) did the trick and it finaly went through same way as on desktop. There was some error compiling httplib (I've read it some issue with encoding), but it compiled anyway and worked.

My buildozer.spec important lines are:

```
requirements = kivy, android, openssl, pyopenssl, httplib2
```

pyopenssl is redundant i guess

```
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

My main.py imports for the test app:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
```

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: I've got this working with just: _kivy,openssl_. I've discovered that a key is to clean the buildozer distribution before rebuilding. Simply changing the requirements and rebuilding doesn't incorporate the new requirements into the binary code. So _buildozer android clean_ then _buildozer android debug deploy run_ should yield positive results.